# Running an application through xcode on my device while I already have the app downloaded from the AppStore

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store

I have an app on the AppStore and have it downloaded on my device.
I am writing some upgrades for the app and want to run and test how everything looks on my device through xcode.
Should I delete the app downloaded from the AppStore or will it replace that app with the one running through xcode?
I am using Facebook login as well, so if my app (downloaded from the AppStore) is already logged in, will the one I run from xcode have any clashes?
I tried running my xcode workspace but the app that runs doesn't seem to reflect the changes.

Any help would be great!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to create different targets or build configurations, one for development and one for production. With the help of preprocessor flags you can have an efficient setup to run both debug and production builds together at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App would replace only one case if your app running from xcode and app from app store having same bundle ID. Now if you want to run both app identically, change bundle id of app running from xcode. Also can use wild bundle id.

Comment: Okay thank you. The bundle ID for both the apps are the same. So basically when I run from xcode, it will replace my app from the app store with the xcode app right?

Comment: Right, It will replace

Answer (score 0):

The app would be replaced when the bundle identifier is the same. Also make sure you increase the build number / version number.